# How to properly concatenate mp4 videos with GStreamer

Tags: linux, gstreamer, embedded-linux, mp4, pts

We are relatively new to GStreamer. We are running GStreamer 1.18.4 on a Linux-based custom board and we have a pipeline receiving video from an IP camera using *rtspsrc* and creating MP4 video clips of 10 seconds.
We faced the *missing PTS issue* and we were able to solved it by implementing the workaround of turning-on the interpolation from our C code (gst_base_parse_set_pts_interpolation on). Now the 10 secs video clips are properly recorded.

The pipeline we are using to create the videos is the following (with the interpolation set to on for the element h264parse):

```
gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc user-id="admin" user-pw="admin" 
location="rtsp://192.168.0.131:554/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=0&unicast=true&proto=Onvif" !
rtph264depay ! h264parse !
splitmuxsink location=video_%02d.mp4 max-files=400 max-size-time=100000000
```

Now we are facing an issue in which we need to concatenate some of those videos(let's say concatenate 6 10secs videos to get a long 1-minute video) and our pipeline often gets broken.

We believe the pipeline gets broken when one of the videos being concatenated has PTS interpolated (the workaround we implemented).

The pipeline we are using to concat is:

```
gst-launch-1.0 concat name=c ! queue ! m.video_0 
    qtmux name=m ! filesink location=/data/users/videos/output_video.mp4
    filesrc location=/data/users/videos/cam1_input_video_1.mp4 ! qtdemux ! h264parse ! c.
    filesrc location=/data/users/videos/cam2_input_video_2.mp4 ! qtdemux ! h264parse ! c.
```

We have tested the pipeline concatenating multiple times the same video and in that case, everything works as expected. Fails (sometimes) when concatenating different files.

We have tried several different modifications to the pipeline, but all of them fail on the *qtdemux* element with the following message:

```
gst-launch-1.0 --gst-debug-level=3 concat name=c ! queue ! m.video_0 qtmux name=m ! filesink location=/data/users/videos/output_video.mp4    filesrc location=/data/users/videos/cam1_input_video_1.mp4 ! qtdemux ! h264parse ! c.    filesrc location=/data/users/videos/cam1_input_video_2.mp4 ! qtdemux ! h264parse ! c. 

Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
0:00:00.461273255 10102   0x60c030 WARN              aggregator gstaggregator.c:2046:gst_aggregator_query_latency_unlocked:<m> Latency query failed
0:00:00.465287035 10102   0x6210a0 WARN                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:3688:gst_base_src_start_complete:<filesrc2> pad not activated yet
0:00:00.466665891 10102   0x6210a0 WARN                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:3688:gst_base_src_start_complete:<filesrc1> pad not activated yet
0:00:00.467579600 10102   0x6210a0 WARN                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:3688:gst_base_src_start_complete:<filesrc0> pad not activated yet
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
0:00:00.471999988 10102   0x60be60 WARN                 qtdemux qtdemux_types.c:245:qtdemux_type_get: unknown QuickTime node type pasp
0:00:00.472496716 10102   0x60be60 WARN                 qtdemux qtdemux.c:3067:qtdemux_parse_trex:<qtdemux2> failed to find fragment defaults for stream 1
0:00:00.475729572 10102   0x60bdb0 WARN                 qtdemux qtdemux_types.c:245:qtdemux_type_get: unknown QuickTime node type pasp
0:00:00.476105597 10102   0x60bdb0 WARN                 qtdemux qtdemux.c:3067:qtdemux_parse_trex:<qtdemux0> failed to find fragment defaults for stream 1
0:00:00.480323577 10102   0x60bef0 WARN                 qtdemux qtdemux_types.c:245:qtdemux_type_get: unknown QuickTime node type pasp
0:00:00.480799931 10102   0x60bef0 WARN                 qtdemux qtdemux.c:3067:qtdemux_parse_trex:<qtdemux1> failed to find fragment defaults for stream 1
0:00:00.525340747 10102   0x60c030 FIXME               basesink gstbasesink.c:3386:gst_base_sink_default_event:<filesink0> stream-start event without group-id. Consider implementing group-id handling in the upstream elements
0:00:00.526037550 10102   0x60c030 WARN                   qtmux gstqtmux.c:3077:gst_qt_mux_start_file:<m> Robust muxing requires reserved-moov-update-period to be set
Pipeline is PREROLLED ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
0:00:00.529879629 10102   0x60c030 FIXME             aggregator gstaggregator.c:1367:gst_aggregator_aggregate_func:<m> Subclass should call gst_aggregator_selected_samples() from its aggregate implementation.
New clock: GstSystemClock
0:00:00.770191724 10102   0x60c090 WARN                   qtmux gstqtmux.c:5346:gst_qt_mux_can_renegotiate:<m> pad video_0 refused renegotiation to video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)avc, alignment=(string)au, level=(string)3.1, profile=(string)main, codec_data=(buffer)014d401fffe1002e674d401f8d8d402802dff80b7010101400000fa000027103a1801e9c0003567ebbcb8d0c00f4e0001ab3f5de5c2801000468ee3880, width=(int)1280, height=(int)720, framerate=(fraction)20000/1001, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, colorimetry=(string)bt709, chroma-format=(string)4:2:0, bit-depth-luma=(uint)8, bit-depth-chroma=(uint)8, parsed=(boolean)true
0:00:00.782437264 10102   0x60c090 WARN                   qtmux gstqtmux.c:5346:gst_qt_mux_can_renegotiate:<m> pad video_0 refused renegotiation to video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)avc, alignment=(string)au, level=(string)3.1, profile=(string)main, codec_data=(buffer)014d401fffe1002e674d401f8d8d402802dff80b7010101400000fa000027103a1801e9c0003567ebbcb8d0c00f4e0001ab3f5de5c2801000468ee3880, width=(int)1280, height=(int)720, framerate=(fraction)20000/1001, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, colorimetry=(string)bt709, chroma-format=(string)4:2:0, bit-depth-luma=(uint)8, bit-depth-chroma=(uint)8, parsed=(boolean)true
0:00:00.783267561 10102   0x60c090 WARN                   qtmux gstqtmux.c:5346:gst_qt_mux_can_renegotiate:<m> pad video_0 refused renegotiation to video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)avc, alignment=(string)au, level=(string)3.1, profile=(string)main, codec_data=(buffer)014d401fffe1002e674d401f8d8d402802dff80b7010101400000fa000027103a1801e9c0003567ebbcb8d0c00f4e0001ab3f5de5c2801000468ee3880, width=(int)1280, height=(int)720, framerate=(fraction)20000/1001, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, colorimetry=(string)bt709, chroma-format=(string)4:2:0, bit-depth-luma=(uint)8, bit-depth-chroma=(uint)8, parsed=(boolean)true
0:00:00.784103274 10102   0x60c090 WARN                   qtmux gstqtmux.c:5346:gst_qt_mux_can_renegotiate:<m> pad video_0 refused renegotiation to video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)avc, alignment=(string)au, level=(string)3.1, profile=(string)main, codec_data=(buffer)014d401fffe1002e674d401f8d8d402802dff80b7010101400000fa000027103a1801e9c0003567ebbcb8d0c00f4e0001ab3f5de5c2801000468ee3880, width=(int)1280, height=(int)720, framerate=(fraction)20000/1001, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, colorimetry=(string)bt709, chroma-format=(string)4:2:0, bit-depth-luma=(uint)8, bit-depth-chroma=(uint)8, parsed=(boolean)true
0:00:00.785129478 10102   0x60c090 WARN                   qtmux gstqtmux.c:5346:gst_qt_mux_can_renegotiate:<m> pad video_0 refused renegotiation to video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)avc, alignment=(string)au, level=(string)3.1, profile=(string)main, codec_data=(buffer)014d401fffe1002e674d401f8d8d402802dff80b7010101400000fa000027103a1801e9c0003567ebbcb8d0c00f4e0001ab3f5de5c2801000468ee3880, width=(int)1280, height=(int)720, framerate=(fraction)20000/1001, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, colorimetry=(string)bt709, chroma-format=(string)4:2:0, bit-depth-luma=(uint)8, bit-depth-chroma=(uint)8, parsed=(boolean)true
0:00:00.793758637 10102   0x60c090 WARN                   qtmux gstqtmux.c:5346:gst_qt_mux_can_renegotiate:<m> pad video_0 refused renegotiation to video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)avc, alignment=(string)au, level=(string)3.1, profile=(string)main, codec_data=(buffer)014d401fffe1002e674d401f8d8d402802dff80b7010101400000fa000027103a1801e9c0003567ebbcb8d0c00f4e0001ab3f5de5c2801000468ee3880, width=(int)1280, height=(int)720, framerate=(fraction)20000/1001, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, colorimetry=(string)bt709, chroma-format=(string)4:2:0, bit-depth-luma=(uint)8, bit-depth-chroma=(uint)8, parsed=(boolean)true
0:00:00.794520312 10102   0x60bef0 WARN                 qtdemux qtdemux.c:6545:gst_qtdemux_loop:<qtdemux1> error: Internal data stream error.
0:00:00.794615432 10102   0x60bef0 WARN                 qtdemux qtdemux.c:6545:gst_qtdemux_loop:<qtdemux1> error: streaming stopped, reason not-negotiated (-4)
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstQTDemux:qtdemux1: Internal data stream error.
Additional debug info:
../gst-plugins-good-1.18.4/gst/isomp4/qtdemux.c(6545): gst_qtdemux_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstQTDemux:qtdemux1:
streaming stopped, reason not-negotiated (-4)
Execution ended after 0:00:00.605594272
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

Any idea how we can improve the pipeline to make the concatenation better and more robust against possible errors/inconsistencies of the PTS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We were able to solve the issue by replacing the *concat* element with *splitmuxsrc*.

The final pipeline we used is:

```
splitmuxsrc name=splitsrc ! h264parse ! qtmux ! filesink name=sink
```

The list of files to be concatenated is passed from C to the *splitsrc* element through the *format-location* signal:

```
GStrv *format_location_callback (GstElement * splitmux,
                      gpointer udata)
```